# Password expiration and reset in Symfony2

Tags: authentication, symfony, passwords

I've changed my `User` class to implement `AdvancedUserInterface`. Now, I get an exception with the message "Credentials expired" when I try to log into an expired account. So far, so good. My next step is to implement a form that will allow the user to create a new password. This password reset process will set the expiration date sometime in the future. It needs to be complete before they enter the restricted area.

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed to [create a custom Authentication Provider](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_authentication_provider.html).